# Favicon not working in Sharepoint 2013 SSL site

Tags: branding, ssl

I'm working on a branding project and I'm unable to get a favicon to display on an internal SSL Sharepoint 2013 site.

If I access the site via http://**servername**:xxxx the favicon displays fine so I know my code in the masterpage is correct.  However, when I access the site via its host name with the SSL, https://groups.contoso.corps it does not work.  To make it more frustrating, it does work in Chrome and Firefox using the SSL link, just not in IE9-11 which is where I need it to work because that is our company's supported browser.

Is there something I'm missing or is there a specific reason IE won't show the favicon on this SSL site?  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestion. I finally found the solution and all I needed to do was add my site to the Trusted Sites section in IE's Internet Options.  I did this via global policy and it's now showing up on all my computers in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It can be related with the location of the icon, do you have tried different locations like

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />

<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/favicon.ico" />
```